# JPA: Map<Enum,Enum> & Map<Enum,Boolean>

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, enums

I'm trying to add a Map entity in two ways:
**Map<Enum,Enum>:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reservations")
public class Reservation {
...
       private Map<Request, RequestImportance> guestsRequests;
...
}
```

**Map<Enum,Boolean>**:

```
public class Room {
    ...
    private Map<Request, Boolean> requestsMap;
}
```

These are the enums Request and RequestImportance:

```
public enum Request {
    ELEVATORPROXIMITY,
    SEAVIEW,
    BATHTUB,
    BALCONY,
    HANDICAPPED,
    HIGHFLOOR
}

public enum RequestImportance {
    NOT_IMPORTANT,
    NICE_TO_HAVE,
    MUST;
}
```

I'm not sure which attributes I'm supposed to use to map to the DB.
I'm using mySQL for this project.

**EDIT:**
Probably not possible to do that. I figured that I would change the Map to a List and create a new Class which contains an Enum field. That way I can represent the data in the DB.

Comment: You can't do that as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

You could use **@ElementCollection** for that

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Request, RequestImportance> guestsRequests = new HashMap<>();
```

By default it is mapped to the table `reservation_guests_requests` that has three columns

- `reservation_id` (refers to `Reservation` obviously)
- `guests_requests_key` (contains `Request` ordinal number)
- `guests_requests` (contains `RequestImportance` ordinal number)

If you are not fine with these names or need to fit the existing table they could be adjusted

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name = "guests_requests",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rsrv_id")
)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "request_n")
@Column(name = "request_importance_n")
private Map<Request, RequestImportance> guestsRequests = new HashMap<>();
```

This time it will be `guests_requests` with

- `rsrv_id` (I guess `reservation_id` is a better name, just showed the possibility to adjust it)
- `request_n`
- `request_importance_n`

On the one hand saving enum ordinal is fine, on the other hand it is sensitive to its order and could make issues if the values are reordered.

Luckily it could be switched to `String` or any custom index or an abbreviation with [AttributeConverter](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters#using-the-converter). If you put `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` above the map it will affect only the value i.e. `RequestImportance`

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: It's probably not possible as far as I understand. I change the Map to a List and added a new Class to the project. That way I can easily use the DB for this type of structure.

Comment: @Tl2 That's up to you, you're the boss here. Anyhow, I extended my answer to show the possibility.